# jQuery: check if input has values auto filled by the browser

Tags: jquery, forms, browser, passwords

If the form input has certain pre-filled values on page load, I want to do certain things to the form.

The following code works fine in all cases **except when the input values are the values saved in browser.**

```
if($("#edit-name").val()!=""){
    //Do something here
}
```

The form shows the values but `console.log($("#edit-name").val());` shows empty logs.
[image: Login Form showing Input Values Auto filled By Browser]

[image: Console.log showing empty output]

How can I detect if the input field has some values automatically filled by browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work as it is, but you need to wait for a little bit until the browser is not setting the values in the field. So you need to use `setTimeout()` for the same. Although it may not be the best way to solve your problem. :)

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($("#edit-name").val()!="") {
            //do stuff here
        }
    }, 100); //hold the code execution for 100 ms
});
```